# Intuition behind formula for matrix inverse in terms of partitions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, intuition

Suppose we have a square matrix $A$ that can be partitioned into $A=\pmatrix{A_{11}&A_{12}\\ A_{21}&A_{22}}$. Then its inverse is given by the formula

$$A^{-1}=\pmatrix{(A_{11} - A_{12}A_{22}A_{21})^{-1}&-A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}(A_{22} - A_{21}A_{11}A_{12})^{-1}\\ -A_{22}^{-1}A_{21}(A_{11} - A_{12}A_{22}A_{21})^{-1}&(A_{22} - A_{21}A_{11}A_{12})^{-1}}$$

Now, we can simply multiply $A^{-1}$ and $A$ to check that this indeed is the correct formula, given $A_{11}$ and $A_{22}$ are not singular.

But is there any intuition (probably geometric) behind why this is so?: The formula does have a pattern in it!

Comment: It's blockwise Gaussian elimination at work. See the Wikipedia entry on [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).

Comment: It is important to say that your formula works only if the diagonal blocks are themselves square (the off diagonal blocks $A_{12}$ and $A_{21}$ can be rectangular)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For easier typesetting, let $$
X=\pmatrix{A&B
\\ C&D
}
$$
The motivation is to block diagonalize as follows:$$
\hat X=
\pmatrix{\hat A&0
\\ 0&\hat D
}=VXW
$$
This could be achieved using

$$\hat X=\pmatrix{I&-BD^{-1}
\\ 0&I} X
\pmatrix{I&0
\\ -D^{-1}C&I
}
$$
You are looking for $$X^{-1}=W\hat XV$$

Solve for the right side and note that the inverse of a block diagonal matrix has its diagonal block elements inversed **(if their inverses exist)**

Also, you can block diagonalize $X$ in any way you want, the one shown is just one of them. As said in the comments, you can look for the [Schur complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)